# Can't Pickle QLabel object in Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, pickle

I am trying to serialize a QLabel subclass using pickle in python but after being unpickled the text does not seem to be set.  What am I doing wrong or what should I be doing instead to make this work?

```
class TestClass(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText("SomeText")

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().__init__()
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

```
        tc = TestClass()
        print(tc.text())
        res = pickle.dumps(tc)
        print(f"Dumps: {res}")
        res = pickle.loads(res)
        print(f"Loads: {res}")
        print("unpickled text:", repr(res.text()))
```

Output:

```
SomeText
Dumps: b'\x80\x03ctestClass\nTestClass\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02b.'
Loads: <testClass.TestClass object at 0x0000027E64146048>
unpickled text: ''
```

I'd expect the text after being unpickled to be the same "SomeText" but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to pickle it now? How did you try and pickle it? What was the specific error?

Comment: your output would suggest that you are not getting an error or anything, it is successfully pickling. Please explain what is not working properly, like is the ui not being updated weirdly?

Comment: print(res.text()) prints nothing

Comment: if you want to keep text then pickle text, not label.

Comment: hey, I edited the question to be clearer with what is going wrong. The original wording suggested that pickle wasn't working at all but it seems to be just not intended behaviour so I made that a little clearer, if I have deviated from your original intent at all feel free to edit again. :) welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your QLabel's state is not maintained by your Python object's internal `__dict__`, so you must (de)serialize it explicitly:

```py
class TestClass(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText("SomeText")

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            "__TEXT__": self.text()
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super().__init__()
        self.setText(state.get("__TEXT__", ""))
```

Output:

```
SomeText
Dumps: b'\x80\x03c__main__\nTestClass\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x08\x00\x00\x00__TEXT__q\x03X\x08\x00\x00\x00SomeTextq\x04sb.'
Loads: <__main__.TestClass object at 0x7f18a90215f0>
unpickled text: 'SomeText'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try this solution!